# Getting different chars sent from same flash form if sent from IE and FF

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, encoding, utf-8

I'm using FLASH form embedded into html which use utf8 charset to send variables and image to php script which saves them mysql.

In flash I do use fileupload method,

`var loc:*=new flash.net.URLRequest("http://url.com/code.php?s=1&name=" + vardas.text + "&email=" + email.text);
                fileHandler.upload(loc);`

**The problem is that when I open and fill up form in INTERNET EXPLORER, i receive not UTF-8 variables in php, but if I use CHROME or FIREFOX, i get them right.**

Is there a difference how IE and other browsers send data? Or do I have to somehow encode variables in action script?

Looking forward for ideas, thanks for reading.

EDIT:
Possible problem - url in IE not supporting chars like č while CHROME AND FF DOES?

Comment: Have you tried using `HTTPService` instead? Might work, I'm not sure...This might help you too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2996350/calling-php-script-with-utf-8-post-variables

Answer (score 1):

```
// fileHandler.upload(loc); // will not encode the data to utf-8



var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
urlLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;

// add your event listeners
urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler );
urlLoader.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, secErrorHandler );
urlLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler );

var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest( "http://url.com/code.php" );
requestVars.name = vardas.text;
requestVars.email = email.text;
request.data = requestVars
//request.method = URLRequestMethod.GET;
request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

try {
  urlLoader.load( request );
} catch (e:Error) {
  trace(e);
}
```

[EDIT]

Here is another example that should work based on your code but prefered method would be the first example.

```
//You should always validate any input from the user that they can manually 
// enter on both client and server side. This will help prevent a plethora
// of things including data injection and many other hacking techniques.

var url:String = 'http://url.com/code.php?s=1'
    url += '&name='  + escape( vardas.text ); 
    url += '&email=' + escape( email.text );

var loc:*=new flash.net.URLRequest(url);

 fileHandler.upload(loc);
```

Comment: Thanks! But why does it encode to UTF8 if I use CHROME or Firefox?

Comment: one other issue there might be the vars you are using need to be escaped for example spaces can not be put on the query string they need to be encoded to %20 there is a function I will edit m,y answer and give an example.

Comment: As far as chrome and FF goes it is probably auto encoding the query string for you. I don't know but just a guess.

Comment: come to think about my first example is flawed also the vars will also need to be escaped there also.

Comment: The first example makes no difference. The second one is the same as the author's post. And he said that it works on Chrome and Firefox, so Flash is already encoding stuff in UTF-8, except that something special (but what?) needs to be done for IE.

Comment: @Laurent the second is not the same. If he doesn't escape the text field data it will break the query string. He needs to escape that is all that needs to be done. What he is seeing is the difference between how the plugin and the activeX controller handle the requests thats all. Its not its not a browser specific issue its an activeX problem with not handling the query properly.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this header in your HTML page?

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`

Comment: Have you tried checking the requests sent by IE with a debugging proxy (such as Fiddler or Charles?). Check that the data is UTF-8 or not. If it is, it's a problem with your server-side PHP script. Do you have some URL we can look at?